# can I use dynamic alias to name a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I just want to know if it is possible to assign dynamic names to a column. for instance:

```
SQL> select sysdate+1 from dual;
SYSDATE+1
---------
09-JUL-08
```

the column name is SYSDATE+1. can I do something like:

```
SQL> select 1 as (select sysdate from dual) from dual;
(this throws error)
```

The reason for this requirement is that I need to assign a column name according to a value that comes from a parameter. So, instead of returning something like:

```
SQL> select sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual;
SYSDATE   SYSDATE+1

--------- ---------

08-JUL-08 09-JUL-08
```

I need to find a way to return something like:

```
SQL> select sysdate as <<dynamic column name based on parameter that has been passed in>>, sysdate+1 AS <<dynamic column name based on parameter that has been passed in>> from dual;
```

Obviously I can use something like:

```
select sysdate as "08-JUL-08", sysdate+1 AS "09-JUL-08" from dual;
```

But in this case I'm hard coding it. I need this alias to be dynamic.

Any way to do it?

Comment: The only way is to use dynamic SQL.  I cannot imagine any scenario where doing this would be a good solution, so I suggest going back to the requirements first and figuring out a better way, a way that doesn't have this (rather ridiculous) constraint.

Comment: In "select sysdate as <>", <> can't be a valid alias because <> is a predefined not equals operator. An alias has to be a proper identifier. Similarly, in "select 1 as (select .." the intent is not clear to me. A dynamic alias can be used with dynamic sql, but alias names have to follow the rules of identifiers.

Comment: It seems to me from this query of yours   `select sysdate as "08-JUL-08", sysdate+1 AS "09-JUL-08"`   that you may actually be looking for pivot and unpivot features.